# Method from included Trait implementation not found in scope in Rust

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I want to use two external libraries (geo-types-0.6.0 and geo-offset-0.1.0) to perform geometric algorithms.

The example below seems fine:
The `Line` type is defined in the library `geo_types`.
The `Offset` trait moreover is written in `geo_offset`. Including this trait should lead to the `Line` type implementing method `offset`.
However I get the following error:

`` no method named `offset` found for struct `geo_types::line::Line<float>` in the current scope ``

In addition to that, the `rust-analyzer` in VS Code tells me, that the included trait `Offset` is not used. Why is that?

```rust
use geo_types::{Coordinate, Line};
use geo_offset::Offset;

let line = Line::new(
    Coordinate { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 },
    Coordinate { x: 1.0, y: 8.0 },
);

let line_with_offset = line.offset(2.0)?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geo-offset` crate implements the `Offset` trait for `geo::Line`, not `geo_types::Line` ([src](https://docs.rs/crate/geo-offset/0.1.0/source/src/offset.rs) - search for `geo::Line`). So even so `geo::Line` is just a re-export of `geo_types::Line`, the rust compiler doesn't see this deep and only knows about the `Offset` implementation for `geo::Line`.

Comment: Maybe because the example on geo-offset is wrong and shows just what you did? Might be worth filing a bug with them ...

Comment: @Nevsden also customary to accept the answer if it fixed the problem. This signals that "this problem has been solved".

Comment: Thanks again, just flagged your answer as the solution.
To your other comment: Yes that is probably the case, I will report it.